# Python with selenium: how to get the first string in element

Tags: python, selenium, datetime, xpath

`HTML`:

```
<td rowspan="2" class="en">17-04-10<br>00:30</td>
```

`Python` code:

```
lb3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@rowspan='2']")
print (lb3.text)
```

the result is:

```
 17-04-10
 00:30
```

I want get the string format like this `17-04-10 00:30` , or just get the date `17-04-10` because I need to convent to `datetime` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally you might need to use

```
//td[@rowspan='2']/text()[1]
```

to get `17-04-10`, but `selenium` doesn't suport this syntax, so you can handle output with `Python` like below:

```
print (lb3.text.split()[0])
```

to get `17-04-10`

or

```
print(" ".join(lb3.text.split()))
```

to get `17-04-10 00:30`

Answer (score 1):

Use replace function replace("\n", "") or text.replace("\r\n","")

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
date=re.search(r'(\d+\S\d+\S\d+)', lb3 , re.I)
date=(date.groups())
print(date)
```

This code will find the first object in the format you describe (the date) and takes it out and stores it as a list. Note that if the page webpages you scrape alternates its month/year delimiter this code will also work.

The regex command (line 2) will yield a match object. Line 3 converts this into a list object.

Granted this does require the creation of an extra list, which might be inefficient.

More information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html